# vorliebnehmen wollen

Tags: meaning

Gestern Abend bin ich auf diese beiden Worte gestoßen, während ich ein Buch las. Aber ich kann ihre Bedeutungen nicht richtig bzw. wörtlich verstehen.

Im Spinnen-Netz (Buch):

> Der Großvater zögerte keine Sekunde. Er erhob sich, stand dann mitten im Raum, groß und kräftig, wie er ist, und machte eine einladende Geste. *"Wenn die Herren mit mir vorliebnehmen wollen - bitte schön!"*

Im Web habe ich für eine ähnliche Übersetzung auf Englisch recherchiert, fand aber eine Definition, die sagt, dass "vorliebnehmen" "make do" ähnlich ist. Aber wenn ich diese beiden Wörter wörtlich übersetzen will, kann ich es nicht richtig verstehen: "If the Gentlemen want to make do with me, please!"

Comment: "Einsende Geste" gibt es nicht - könnte da "einladende Geste" (inviting gesture) stehen?

Answer (score 4):

> vorliebnehmen mit ...

bedeutet englisch etwa

> (enforcedly) to be content with ...

Der [Kontext](https://www.beltz.de/fileadmin/beltz/leseproben/978-3-407-74260-5.pdf) ist hier wichtig.

> ... und die fünf Grauen drangen in den Raum und fragten, ohne jeden Gruß und ohne sich auf irgendeine Weise vorzustellen, laut und barsch: "Welcher von den Anwesenden ist der Zimmerermeister Friedrich Wilhelm Jacobi?"
>   Der Großvater zögerte keine Sekunde. Er erhob sich, stand dann mitten im Raum, groß und kräftig, wie er ist, und machte eine einladende Geste. "Wenn die Herren mit mir vorliebnehmen wollen – bitte schön!"

Die Polizisten sind offenbar sehr unhöflich und roh, von seiner großen und kräftigen Gestalt aber sicher etwas eingeschüchtert. Deshalb drückt er das in dieser (ironischen) Weise aus. Eine Übersetzung könnte also etwa so lauten:

> If the gentlemen would be content with me - here I am.

Answer (score 2):

Eine Vorliebe ist eine Präferenz. Man hat eine Vorliebe für etwas, etwa Marzipankugeln auf dem Weihnachtsteller.

*Vorlieb nehmen* ist daher *bevorzugen, präferieren* (to prefer).

Als feststehender Ausdruck taucht "vorliebnehmen", insbesondere als Appell, oft dann auf, wenn jemand abweichend von seinen Präferenzen seine zweite Wahl zur ersten machen muss: "Der Espresso ist alle - würden Sie auch mit einem einfachen Kaffee vorlieb nehmen?"

Die Präferenz des einfachen Kaffees besteht hier nicht gegenüber dem Espresso, der aus Sachzwängen aus dem Spiel ist, sondern gegenüber Tee oder gar nichts zu trinken.

Der Großvater bietet sich hier also als zweite Wahl an. Als Übersetzung schlägt mir DeepL auch make-do vor.

> "If the gentlemen want to make do with me - please, go ahead!

Ist mir nicht geläufig, aber wird dann wohl stimmen.

Comment: Als Nebenbemerkung, "to make do" geht eher in Richtung "mit etwas zurecht kommen" oder "etwas zum Funktionieren bringen". "Ich hätte eigentlich einen 3-Zoll-Muffenflanschheber gebraucht, aber mit einem 3,5-Zoll-Dichtungsprüfschlüssel geht es notfalls auch".